# Do some operation in child popup window in selenium

Tags: selenium, automation

I am trying to do the SBI application and after cliking login and when i click on Forgot Password Link child Pop up window appears and want to do click operation on Next using Automation in Child Pop window.
Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code

Comment: hi, thank you but I don't know how to share the code. This is the scenario I have to launch this https://www.onlinesbi.com/ website and perform action on forgot password link and get a child popup window and have to perform an action on Next button.